# How to use gtest for the functions that have no arguments but still do calculations?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, googletest

AFAIK the [basic document of gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md) shows examples of functions with arguments.

I have to test functions which are slots to some signals. One of them does not have any parameters. Internally it fetches socket data, parses it using local variables, and then assigns values to class members.

What would be a way to test such a thing through gtest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate it to two functions. One is core which takes arguments and the other is a wrapper that fetches socket data and pass it to the core. For example:

```
result compute_core(data x);
result compute_wrapper(){
    auto x=read_from_socket();
    return compute_core(x);
}
```

Now you can test `compute_core` as much as you want.

Comment: Separation on concerns is the first step to logical well tested code. Note that process of reading from a socket can now be tested in isolation. +1

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Yes, you should

Answer (score 3):

The question has already been answered well, but I felt it might add some value to add some narrative.

The idea of a "function with no arguments" is actually an oxymoron.

If a function has no arguments, then it's actually either a constant, a process or a no-operation.

If it returns a value without generating observable side-effects, then it's a constant and you already know what the return value should be. You can simply `ASSERT_EQ` the return value.

If it has side-effects (consuming from sockets, emitting data to streams, storing data in databases, or in a framework, etc) then it's a process.

If it's a process, then it can't be unit-tested in isolation. A process has (possibly many) inputs and outputs. And the effect of the former on the latter is what you're testing.

In which case the test would look like this:

```
{
    set_up_process_dependencies();
    inject_known_data_into_the_process_possibly_via_dependencies();
    call_process();
    ASSERT_EQ(x, test_some_output_of_the_process());
    ...
}
```

Which starts to look more like an integration test than a unit test.